# Windows 7 Backup Fails with 0x81000033

Tags: windows-7, backup

I am attempting to take my first backup on a new Windows 7 installation.  It's failing with the error code 0x81000033.

I have already followed the instructions on http://www.pagestart.com/win7br0x8100003301.html, increasing my SystemBoot partition from 300 to 512 MBytes, but that did not fix the problem.

I have a 480 GB Samsung (MZ7WD480) SSD drive partitioned into three partitions:

1. C: 246 GB, with 158 GB free
2. F: 200 GB, with 154 GB free
3. SystemBoot 512 MB, with 235 MB free

The backup location is the B: drive. It has a single 2794 GB partition with 2205 GB free.

The backup fails with this message:

> Windows backup skipped backing up system image because of of the critical volumes is not having enough free space. Free up some space by deleting unnecessary files and try again.

Details:

> Backup location: Backup (B:)
>
> Error code: 0x81000033

The Backup and Restore control panel says that the size of the (failed) backup is on 1.99 GB, so there has to be plenty of room on the B: drive.

From the error message, I can't even tell which partition it might be complaining about.  Does anyone have any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just attempted to create a system image and got a better and longer error message.  It said that for partitions larger than 500 MB there must be 320 MB of free space.  I have only 235 on the SystemBoot volume. I used gpartd to expand the SystemBoot volume to 2 GB.

Now I was able to sucessfully create both the System Image *and* run the Backup!

So the bottom line is that when Backup complains about not enough space, it's not talking about the source or destination of the backup.  It also needs space on the SystemBoot (or what ever it's called on your computer) partition.

I would let the people over at pagestart.com know this too, but I can't find a way to comment on their mostly correct article or even a way to contact them.  Sigh.